# Detect if user liked my FB page, and remove DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've made a popup box for my site, which invites visitors to Like my page on FB. I wanted to know if there's a way to detect people who have liked the page, and remove the popup box (= a div), so it doesn't loads for them, everytime they browse back the site.

Don't know if this is possible, but I wanted to know. Here's the script I have for this, just in case you need it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var dom = {};
dom.query = jQuery.noConflict(true);
var time = 11;

window.setInterval(test, 1000);

function test()
{
    time -=1;
    dom.query('#fb-timer').html(time); 

    if(time == 0)        
    {
        dom.query('#fb-popupdiv').remove();
    }
} 
function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
   else var expires = "";
   document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
       if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);

    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    setCookie(name,"",-1);
}
dom.query(document).ready(function() {
    var val = readCookie("popupAlreadyShown");
    if (!val) {
        setCookie("popupAlreadyShown", 1, 1);
        dom.query("#fb-popupdiv").show();
    } else {
}
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way you can know from facebook's end that whether the page was liked or not unless you have access to user's likes. But for that you'll have to get the user signup via facebook connect.

Most of the like gates/popups use cookie to keep track of the like. When the user likes the page, facebooks's edge.create is used to listen to the like and a cookie is created. If the cookie is cleared the popup will appear again.

More about fb events:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer, vivek. Maybe I just want that users who have liked the page doesn't get the popup if they reload the site, or visit in any other time, without 'neccessarily' detect them. Is that possible?

Comment: You need them to log in using your app and grant you access to their list of likes

Comment: Agree with lgy and I mentioned the same thing in my answer. Other than that there's no way.

Comment: Ahhh, ok, I got it now :/. Thanks for your answers guys!

Answer (score 2):

You want to take a look at the [edge.Create](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) event. Subscribe to it, and perform whatever functions you want within it. For example:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: '1234567890', status: true, cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {
            $("#facebookdiv").hide();
            // set a variable or a cookie so it doesn't show on future requests
        });
</script>
```

**From the Facebook documentation on the page I linked:**

**edge.create** - fired when the user likes something (fb:like). The response parameter to the callback function contains the URL that was liked:

```
"http://www.example.com/article1.php"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Scott. But how do I subscribe to that event, sorry I don't understand how to do it. Should I add that code to my script?